# Unable to ping local systems from freshly installed Ubuntu Linux 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firefox, dns, ping

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I let the installation process configure one of the two ethernet nics on my system. The default interface got set up for DHCP, which for the moment is fine. I can get to any web site with FireFox. I can use apt-get to install software. I can ping my gateway, but I cannot ping any addresses that are not on my subnet. For instance, I cannot ping my nameservers, but I have no idea how FireFox is resolving web site names.Here's what my Connection Information looks like.
[Connection Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrskK.png)

I have been beating my head against the wall for several days. I've tried running the system off of a USB stick and running the system off of an internal SSD. But nothing seems to work. I am certainly open to any and all suggestions how to trouble-shoot this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Some insight into your network topology would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The router that is your default gateway may not be allowing ICMP traffic - so no pings, no traceroute, etc.

You can try using TCP connections instead.  The `hping` utility allows that - https://backdrift.org/tcp-ping-ping-tcp-port